# Using askopenfilename in Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm having a bit of trouble. When I use askopenfilename, it works perfect on Windows and Linux, but Mac seems to be giving me the finger....

Here's an example:

```py
... (Code before all this)
def openFile(self):
    self.fileName = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*")])

... (Code after all this)
```

The issue is that when I click the open button I have, this method is invoked, and opens the dialog even on Mac, BUT everything in the dialog is grayed out and will not let me select any files. Why not? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

So I figured it out. For anyone who may run into this issue, only use filetypes for systems that use file type drop menus. Since Mac does not, just don't include the filetypes tuple.

Example, check for the system running, if it's windows, use filetypes, if mac, don't include it